# What is the normal closure of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ inside $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

This weird problem popped up in my research:

Let $\ell$ be a prime. Is there a description of the smallest normal subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ containing $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Is there a description of the corresponding quotient group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the subgroup of these elements in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_\ell)$ with determinant in $\pm 1$. Thus the quotient is naturally isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathbf{Z}_\ell^\times$ by $\{\pm 1\}$.

Indeed, denote by $e_{ij}(x)$ (for $i\neq j$) the matrix with entry $(i,j)$ equal to $x$, diagonal entries equal to 1, and other entries 0, and $d_i(x)$, for $x$ invertible, the diagonal matrix with $(i,i)$ entry equal to $x$, and other diagonal entries equal to $1$; write $s_{ij}(x)=d_i(x)d_j(x^{-1})$. Then, for $\{i,j\}=\{1,2\}$, and $x\in \mathbf{Z}_\ell^\times$, we have $s_{ij}(x)e_{ij}(1)s_{ij}(x)^{-1}=e_{ij}(x^2)$. Since any element in $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$ is a sum of squares (of 2 squares for $\ell$ odd, 4 squares for $\ell=2$, if I remember correctly), it follows that the normal closure of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ contains all matrices $e_{ij}(y)$ for any $y\in\mathbf{Z}_\ell$. Since such matrices generate $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_\ell)$ (because it's a Euclidean ring), we deduce that the normal closure of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ is all of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_\ell)$. (The same simple argument work in $\mathrm{SL}_d$ for $d\ge 2$.) Now since $\det(\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})=\{\pm 1\}$, we get the result.

(Thanks to grghxy for a correction, I was initially essentially thinking of $\mathrm{SL}_2$ and $\mathrm{GL}_2$ makes an issue with the determinant.)

Comment: One has to be careful about the "torus" quotient. More specifically, this argument shows that one gets at least ${\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{Z}_{\ell})$, so the answer is actually the image of ${\rm{GL}}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ in the abelian ${\rm{GL}}_2(\mathbf{Z}_{\ell})/{\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}) = \mathbf{Z}_{\ell}^{\times}$ (via det), and this image is $\mathbf{Z}^{\times}$. So the normal closure is generated by ${\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{Z}_{\ell})$ and diag($u, 1$) for $u \in \mathbf{Z}^{\times}$, with quotient $\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}^{\times}/\mathbf{Z}^{\times}$.

Comment: Also, a softer way to handle the squares (which works with more general integer rings in place of $\mathbf{Z}$) is to note that since the subset of squares in $\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}$ is open, the $\mathbf{Z}$-submodule they generate inside $\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}$ is open and hence closed, so it is a $\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}$-submodule. But it contains 1, so that $\mathbf{Z}$-submodule coincides with $\mathbf{Z}_{\ell}$.

Comment: Since ${\rm{diag}}(t,1/t)=u^+(t)u^{-}(-1/t)u^+(t-1)u^{-}(1)u^+(-1)$ for units $t$ and standard parameterizations $u^{\pm}$ of standard root groups of ${\rm{SL}}_2$, for any ring $R$ and *simply connected* Chevalley $R$-group $G$ the subgroup of $G(R)$ generated by $U_a(R)$'s for roots $a$ contains $\Omega(R)$ for an open cell $\Omega$. If $R$ is *local* then $\ker(G(R)\rightarrow G(k))\subset \Omega(R)$  (as $\Omega$ is an open subscheme of $G$), and translates of $\Omega$ by Weyl-representatives cover $G$ (enough on geometric fibers!), so $U_a(R)$'s generate $G(R)$ (no Euclidean stuff).

Comment: The Euclidean argument works; yes I'm aware there are plenty of variants and generalizations, and since the question was about $\mathrm{SL}_2$ I chose the most elementary argument I had in mind.

Comment: (But it's true that both $R$ local or $R$ Euclidean imply $\mathrm{SL}_2(R)$ generated by elementary matrices, and the argument when $R$ is local is the simpler one.)

Comment: @YCor Would you happen to have any idea about the normal closure of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) = Out(F_2)$ inside $Out(\widehat{F_2})$? (Here $\widehat{F_2}$ is the pro-$\ell$ completion of the free group of rank 2).

Actually I'm only interested in the $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-case anyway, so the question is - is the normal closure of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ inside $Out(\widehat{F_2})$ the full preimage of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ under the abelianization map $Out(\widehat{F_2})\rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$?

Comment: No, I don't know much about $\mathrm{Out}(\hat{F_2})$, maybe just ask an independent question.

Comment: You mean: under the abelianization map Out$(\hat{F_2})\to GL_2(\mathbf{Z}_\ell)$.

Comment: Yes sorry thats what I meant.